# How do I route with variable actions and keys?

Tags: php, zend-framework, routes, zend-framework2

I am working in Zend Framework 2 and have variable actions and primary keys.  Below is my modules router.  I would like to pass different ID's to it based on the action  (If I delete the language it will reference a languageId if I delete an album it will reference an albumId). Do I need to create child routes for language and album and then identify the specific ID used for each child route?  Or is there a way where I can say the second parameter will always be a number and the action will do what it needs to with that number?

Action: deleteLanguage  ID: languageId
ACtion: deleteAlbum     ID: albumId

```
 'router' => array(
     'routes' => array(
         'pro' => array(
             'type'    => 'segment',
             'options' => array(
                 'route'    => '/pro[/][:action][/:id]',
                 'constraints' => array(
                     'action' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                     'language_id' => '[0-9]+',
                 ),

                 'defaults' => array(
                     'controller' => 'Pro\Controller\Pro',
                     'action'     => 'index',
                 ),
```

Many Thanks,
M

Comment: Whilst you could do this with multiple routes, just using `id` as the variable name on each would seem a lot simpler.

Comment: Thank you Jurian! I ended up breaking it out into multiple controllers.  Thanks for the tip (my controller was getting a little to big)  This helps to keep it more manageable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only can create a dependency between the action and the identifier if you write down the configuration completely. ZF2 has no method to rename parameter names based on other parameter values (and if you think about it, there are plenty good reasons not to have this feature).

You are left with two options:

```php
'pro' => [
    'type'    => 'literal',
    'options' => [
        'route'    => '/pro',
        'defaults' => [
            'controller' => 'Pro\Controller\Pro',
            'action'     => 'index',
        ],
        'may_terminate' => true,
        'child_routes' => [
            'delete-language' => [
                'type'    => 'segment',
                'options' => [
                    'route'    => '/delete-language/:language_id',
                    'defaults' => [
                        'action' => 'deleteLanguage'
                    ],
                    'constraints' => [
                        'language_id' => '[0-9]+'
                    ],
                ],
            ],
            'delete-album' => [
                'type'    => 'segment',
                'options' => [
                    'route'    => '/delete-album/:album_id',
                    'defaults' => [
                        'action' => 'deleteAlbum'
                    ],
                    'constraints' => [
                        'album_id' => '[0-9]+'
                    ],
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ],
]
```

Or accept you deal with an "id" only (which is much more preferred imho):

```
'pro' => [
    'type'    => 'segment',
    'options' => [
        'route'    => '/pro[/:action[/:id]]',
        'defaults' => [
            'controller' => 'Pro\Controller\Pro',
            'action'     => 'index',
        ],
        'constraints' => [
            'id' => '[0-9]+'
        ],
    ],
]
```

Also, it helps a lot if you split your controllers per entity / domain model. Don't put a delete for a "language" and a delete for an "album" in the same controller. Split them! Think more in RESTful principles and it will keep your code much cleaner.